# Where do I place unset and unlink in php?

Tags: php

I have some php code. I wish to unset topic and unlink $outputfile once I have finished printing it.

```
$file = "files/textfile.txt" ;
$processed = "processed.txt" ;
$outputfile = "files/outputfile.txt" ;

if(!empty($_POST)){
    writetofile($file, $text, "w");
    preproc($file);
    execpython($processed);

    $topic = getoutput($outputfile);
}
```

So, I am printing it somewhere at the bottom:

```
echo '<span style="color:red;">' . $topic . '</span>';
```

I am not sure how should I place `unlink` and `unset` because they seem to be deleting the outputfile in advance and I don't receive any output then. I need to delete it because it is being over-written and producing the same output sometimes.

Comment: "once I have finished printing it" - so wouldn't that imply you should put unset/unlink AFTER the code that does the printing?

Comment: You can unlink after you call `getoutput`, and you can unset after you echo `$topic`.

Comment: there is a fundamental problem here ... you are trying to `echo` the `array` `$topic` that doesn't work

Comment: No, I didn't add the entire implementation of the printing process because it's pretty long and I think it isn't very useful to my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the file after you read from it with `getoutput()`, and you can unset the variable after you're finished printing it.

```
$file = "files/textfile.txt" ;
$processed = "processed.txt" ;
$outputfile = "files/outputfile.txt" ;

if(!empty($_POST)){
    writetofile($file, $text, "w");
    preproc($file);
    execpython($processed);

    $topic = getoutput($outputfile);
    unlink($outputfile);
}
echo '<span style="color:red;">' . $topic . '</span>';
unset($topic);
```

Comment: but doing so too, is deleting the file before hand.. It gives me errors like: file not found

Comment: I don't see how that can be. Statements are executed in order, so `getoutput` reads the contents of the file before it's deleted.